# Combo box selectedItem with objects... does not seem to work

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've working with this code for about 3 hours and I can't make it work. I fill a ComboBox with a list of objects (clsMarcas) and when I use the SelectedItem property and assign to it an object of the same type to make it display the DisplayMember, nothing happends. Could you please guide me?

```
public class clsMarcas
{
    public int IdMarca {get; set;}
    public string NombreMarca {get; set;}
    public clsMarcas()
    {

    }
    public clsMarcas(string strMarca)
    {
        this.NombreMarca = strMarca;
    }

}


public class clsAuto
{
    public string Dominio {get; set;}
    public clsMarcas Marca {get; set;}        

    public clsAuto()
    {

    }

    public clsAuto(string Dominio, clsMarcas Marca)
    {
        this.Dominio = Dominio;
        this.Marca = Marca;
    }
}


public partial class frmAutosAE
{
    public frmAutosAE()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private clsAuto oAuto;
    private clsMarcas defaultMarca;

    protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        CargarMarcas();

        if (oAuto != null)
        {
            this.txtDominio.Text = oAuto.Dominio;
            SeleccionarMarca(oAuto.Marca);

        }
    }


    private void SeleccionarMarca(clsMarcas Marca)
    {
        cboMarcas.SelectedItem = Marca;

    }
    public void SetAuto(clsAuto oAuto)
    {
        this.oAuto = oAuto;
    }

    public clsAuto GetAuto()
    {
        return oAuto;
    }

    private void CargarMarcas()
    {
        List<clsMarcas> ListaMarcas = GestorDeRepositorio.GetInstancia().Repositorio.GetMarcas();
        this.cboMarcas.DisplayMember = "NombreMarca";
        defaultMarca = new clsMarcas { NombreMarca = "<Seleccione una marca>" };
        cboMarcas.Items.Add(defaultMarca);
        cboMarcas.SelectedIndex = 0;

        foreach (clsMarcas elemento in ListaMarcas)
        {
            this.cboMarcas.Items.Add(elemento);
        }
    }



    public void btnGuardar_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validarDatos())
        {
            if (oAuto == null)
            {
                oAuto = new clsAuto();
            }

            oAuto.Dominio = this.txtDominio.Text;
            oAuto.Marca=GetMarcaSeleccionada();


            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }



    private clsMarcas GetMarcaSeleccionada()
    {
        clsMarcas marca=(clsMarcas)cboMarcas.SelectedItem;
        if (marca==defaultMarca)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return marca;
    }



    public void btnCancelar_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    }


    public List<clsMarcas> GetMarcas()
    {
        Marcas.Clear();
        try
        {

            using (OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                OleDbTransaction tran = cnn.BeginTransaction();
                string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Marcas";
                OleDbCommand comando = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, cnn, tran);

                using (OleDbDataReader oReader = comando.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (oReader.Read())
                    {
                        clsMarcas oMarca = new clsMarcas();
                        oMarca.IdMarca = oReader.GetInt32(0);
                        oMarca.NombreMarca = oReader.GetString(1);
                        Marcas.Add(oMarca);
                    }

                }

                tran.Commit();

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw (ex);
        }
        return Marcas;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if is the answer, but I can't see a definition for cboMarcas in the code, so may not fully work.

Comment: cboMarcas is likely to have been generated by the windows forms designer.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the problem you are encountering. Also, please try to remove the code which you think is irrelevant to the question. For example, reading the list of `clsMarcas` from the database is not relevant. Code written in Spanish (at least I think it's Spanish) is confusing enough, so try to be as precise as you can regarding your problem.

Comment: I know, similar to Flash. Don't "need" do define but all will work with default definitions - like var types.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the complete code but this likely won't work because when you assign the object to DisplayMember, it is probably not the same object (in memory) than the one you loaded with the list. (Unless your repository reuses object instances, which is unlikely).

Therefore, when the combo box looks for the object you are assigning in the list, it does not find it.

Try to override the Equals method of clsMarcas to provide equality based on the ID (for instance).

Otherwise, try to select by index, or locate the object yourself in the list (based on the ID) and then assign DisplayMember to the instance of the object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

## First, clean your code

Don't override OnLoad, add an [event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx) instead.

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

Should be changed to

```
public frmAutosAE()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Load += FormLoaded;
}

public void FormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
}
```

Use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) instead of setter/getter methods:

```
public void SetAuto(clsAuto oAuto)
{
    this.oAuto = oAuto;
}
    
public clsAuto GetAuto()
{
    return oAuto;
}
```

Should be

```
public clsAuto Auto { get; set; }
```

Use `using` directives instead of fully qualified names:

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
```

Should be

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; 
// add using System.Windows.Forms to the top of the file
```

And finally, please learn the C# naming conventions and use them. Classes begin with a capital letter, local variables don't.

## Then fix your problems

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    CargarMarcas();

    if (oAuto != null)
    {
        this.txtDominio.Text = oAuto.Dominio;
        SeleccionarMarca(oAuto.Marca);

    }
}
```

This is the only place where you call `SeleccionarMarca`. Here, `oAuto` will *always* be null, so the selection code *will **never** be called*. Initialize `oAuto` to solve the problem.

However, as Xavier Poinas pointed out in his answer, you will most likely also need to override `Equals` in clsMarcas, for instance like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var marcas = obj as clsMarcas;
    if (marcas != null)
    {
        return IdMarca == marcas.IdMarca;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This solution has been tested on my machine and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set SelectedItem in Load event and after. Do not set SelectedItem in the form's constructor